# Accessing/Viewing table on a webpage

Tags: web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I am very new to web scraping and I am trying to scrape:

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/turkey/1-lig-2019-2020/results/

Browser: Chrome

I am trying to scrape the table and then use it in beautifulsoup.

When I click on the table, I am not able to highlight the html for the table and hence, unable to proceed further.

[image: Inspect Element]

Am I doing it right? Or am I looking at the wrong place for the table?

Comment: What exactly were you doing? Right-click some element on the page and choose "inspect" in the menu. You can also use Ctrl-Shift-C hotkey. Note though the page generates the table in its JS script (apparently by using a WebSocket) so if beautifulsoup doesn't run scripts you won't see the table in python.

Comment: Oh.. alright, I need to click inspect element at the place I want to inspect and not the general area. Gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to click "inspect element" at the place I want to inspect and not the general area